# Conjectures that can be tested with large numbers of Hecke eigenvalues of GSp(4) automorphic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, big-list, automorphic-forms, computational-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

As part of my thesis work I have proved Ibukiyama's conjecture implies something about $\mathrm{SO}(5)$ forms associated to certain lattices lifting to $\mathrm{GSp}(4)$ (This was originally a discovery/conjecture Jeffery Hein, Gonzalo Tornaria and I made together)

Now the computers of the Berkeley math department have made big lists of (some) paramodular forms in $S_3(K(p))$ for $p<1000$, each one with hopefully 100 Hecke eigenvalues computed (for small $p$ a lot more Hecke eigenvalues, for big $p$ fewer as the calculation gets hard and there are CPU limits in play). There also are some oddball forms I get when I try to go to squarefree level in general which I don't quite know where they live, but some of them correspond to hypergeometric motives (something David P. Roberts helped me discover)

What conjectures should/can I test? Any particularly interesting examples you wish you knew more Hecke eigenvalues for? I already know about Harder's conjecture and plan on examining that. And yes, this will go to the LMFDB someday. Sadly I can't get the coefficients of the forms, only Hecke eigenvalues. Weight 3 is where everything has been computed so far, but that definitely can be extended. Currently I'm working on nonsquarefree levels in order to find more corresponding hypergeometric motives as they tend to have very nonsquarefree conductors.